# (Code by Zapier) Return a list of values from multiple if statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier

The goal of the code is to display a statement only if the value from the variable is “FALSE”. It’s working now, but I would like to list multiple values with line breaks as a part of a single return for Zapier.

With Zapier, every object that is returned from your array will be classified as a line item. I can put these line items in an email with a page break between them, but I would like everything to be outputted together with page breaks so that there is just a single line item.

In the email it will should like this:

```html
You’re missing:<br>
Item 1<br>
Item 2<br>
Item 5<br>
Item 7
```

However, If I put each line item from zapier into the email and put a page break between them it will look something like this:

```html
You’re missing:<br>
Item 1<br>
Item 2<br>
<br>
Item 5<br>
<br>
Item 7
```

With this current method, it places page breaks wherever there is a missing item. So I’d like to just output one thing with the JS, then bring that into Zapier’s email sending tool. Hope that makes sense!

Here is the code:

The inputData.COL1 comes from a spreadsheet and it will be either TRUE or FALSE.

```js
var COL1 = inputData.COL1;
var item1 = (COL1 === "FALSE") ? "Adult Manikin with Feedback Devices" : "";

var COL2 = inputData.COL2;
var item2 = (COL2 === "FALSE") ? "Extra Batteries for AED Trainers" : "";

output = {item1, item2};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I ended up just putting br (page break markup in html) at the end of each output so that it was placed in the final output with the appropriate br's

Got it!